# Create a new Oracle Application Express (APEX)

Tags: database, oracle, server, oracle-apex-5

Let me explain my situation. 
Now I need to create a new APEX application. But I am not using the APEX SQL Workshop (***Figure 1***) as the database. The data is being retrieved through package. 
Please refer to the hierarchy design in ***Figure 2***. From the hierarchy, the data are stored in Table_A in D1EDATA. D1EDATA has a package called Package_A. D1APEX is the application. It calls the package to select, update or delete the records stored in Table_A

Figure 1: Development Environment

[image]

Figure 2: Application Architecture Design

[image]

---

**My questions as below:**

1. How can I call the function/procedure in a package from APEX application?
2. How can I get the logged in user id. Which table is storing the APEX user details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First question is quite simple: to run function/procedure in apex application, you have to do following:

   - create a page in your application (or use previously created)
   - click <kbd>+</kbd> button near the `Regions` label to create new region;
   - in create region wizard, choose `Form` - `Form on a procedure`
   - on next steps choose your procedure/function and fill other required fields.

Apex will create a form with fields for every procedure/function parameters and with buttons `Run` (I don't remember exact name) and `Cancel`.

2. Your second question is quite big. First of all, it depends on your authentication scheme. There is a lot of options: database accont, APEX account, custom, LDAP and many others.

   - database account - you use accounts of database to log in into your application. In this case apex uses logins and passwords in system oracle tables.
   - APEX account - you use developer aacounts to log in into APEX IDE and the same accounts - to log in into the application.
   - custom scheme - you create yourself all tables, procedures for check user login and password, etc.

**UPD**
You can define name of your user (regardless of current authentication scheme) in PL/SQL code with `v` function: `v('APP_USER')`. But remember, this function returns `NULL`, if you call it not from APEX application. There is a universal way to call it (in `UPDATE` statement):

```
update mt_table set username = nvl(v('APP_USER'), user);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. Regarding the question 2, the example is: The user updates a record in APEX application. When a user clicks on the submit button, APEX will call a procedure A in D1APEX interface and procedure A will call a procedure B in D1EDATA to update the particular record. And for my situation, I want to UPDATE the column UpdatedBy with the username.Both the packages are written in Toad

Comment: @Jonas And you want to know, how to get a name of APEX user in PL/SQL, right? Something like this: `update mt_table set username = v('APP_USER')`

Comment: If I want to get the username in Oracle APEX, can I use the code like  update_template( p_last_update_by  => :USER); ?

Comment: No, parameter with name of user in APEX is `APP_USER`, not `USER`.

Comment: I have executed `select v('USER')from dual` in SQL Workshop, it returns the login name too

Comment: If it works, then OK. I have never met this in documentation.

Comment: Anyway, you're so expert in this topic. Thanks for your feedback